# How do you style first date and last date of a range p-calendar?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

Is there a property to style the first date and last date of a p-calendar from [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/calendar). When styling the p-highlight it changes all elements in the range to the style. Is there a way to specify the first element and last element styles in css to create a range selection like the following:

[image: Range Calendar]

Are there any other ways to do this other than through css?

html:

```
    <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
        <p-calendar selectionMode="range"></p-calendar>
    </div>
```

Style sheet:

```
.p-datepicker {
    background: whitesmoke;
    color: gray;

    table {
        font-size: 12px;
        color:#f4f4f4;

        td {
            padding: .5rem;
            color: black;
            &.p-datepicker-other-month{
                color: transparent;

            }

            > span {
                width: 2.5rem;
                height: 2.5rem;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border: 1px solid transparent;

                &.p-highlight {
                    // Active circle
                    color: #f4f4f4;
                    background: orange;

                    &.p-disabled{
                        background: transparent;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: using `:first-child` and `:last-child` css selectors would be the easiest way to approach this imo. However its difficult to say for sure without seeing any of the code associated

Comment: @JDawwgy, Thank you for the feedback. I added the associated code as suggested. Which properties would need these selectors?

Comment: I always fumble a bit trying to get these selectors to work the way I want, but I took a quick look at the PrimeNG calendar and your going to want to try and target the `td` that has the "active" class on it

Answer (score 0):

Didn't found a way to do it by css and I am not sure it could be achieved.

But javascript/typescript should do the job:

.html:

```
<div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
    <p-calendar (onSelect)="onDateSelected($event)" selectionMode="range"> 
    </p-calendar>
</div>
```

.ts:

```
onDateSelected(event: any) : void {
    const rangeLength = document.getElementsByClassName('p-highlight').length;
    document.getElementsByClassName('p-highlight')[0].style.background = 'blue';

    if(rangeLength>0)
        document.getElementsByClassName('p-highlight')[rangeLength-1].style.background = 'blue';
}
```